# Deleting messages that start with certain prefix [discord.py]

Tags: python, discord, discord.py

I want my bot to delete all messages that are not starting with the prefix `.`. I wrote this code so far in discord.py but it keeps deleting all messages.

```py
@Client.event
async def on_message(message):
    if message.author.has_role("Bot"):
        return
    elif message.content.startswith('.'):
        return
    else:
        await message.delete()
```

Thanks in advance

Comment: There's no such thing as `Member.has_role`, you should be getting an attribute error, where did you get it from?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try doing it like this:

```py
@client.event
async def on_message(ctx):
    if ctx.content.startswith('.'):
        await client.process_commands(ctx)
        return

    for role in ctx.author.roles:
        if role.name == 'Bot':
            return
    
    await ctx.delete()
```

Answer (score -2):

I would do it like this:

```
@Client.event
async def on_message(message):
    if message.content.startswith(".") == False:
       message.channel.purge(limit=1)
    else:
         pass
```

Comment: Using `purge` is bad because it might delete the wrong message in case two were sent in rapid succession. Just call `await message.delete()` to make sure the right one was removed. Also, `if condition == False` should be written as `if not condition`.